# What is the best way to secure calls to internal APIs?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am quite new to the django-rest-framework and building APIs, and I am thinking of way to secure my APIs.

**My question is:**

How to allow only your front-end application(AngularJS) to call specific (django-rest-framework's)API endpoints?

For the time being I have set permission to all my Views to be `IsAdminUser`. Also I have created superuser account(for the front-end app). First step is that my front-end app sends requests to login endpoint which authenticates an app, and if successfull, it sends back user token to allow futher API calls. Then user is able to register and/or login, and as soon as he authenticates using his own details, further requests are executed using his own token.

It is working however it is quite spoof. Can someone with more experience advise me on how to allow my APIs to be called only by my front-end client?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @lin I dont understand how is it off-topic?

Comment: Please check point 4, 5 & 6 near the headline  `Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:`.

Comment: @lin I have rewrote the question. Is it better that way?

Comment: No m8, sorry. Its nothing offense but there are hundreds of possible answers/approaches to your question. You looking for an "advise" -> advises are primary opinion based.

Comment: I think you can add a custom HTTP header with a custom value and send it from Angular app along with every requires to your API, kind a "sign" your every request.

Comment: Why do you need to secure login endpoint? Looks like useless overengeneering. Even if you provide some token or credentials "hackers" can just copy it from the request.

Comment: @raz I do not secure login endpoint. I am using login end point to authenticate my client as a first step, so obviously it is not secured. I agree that token or credentials might be intercepted, so thats why I am looking for some other way than that, if there is any? :)